# Borland Teamsource - break admin lock

Tags: delphi

I work at a shop which uses Delphi for fat-client development, and uses Borland's Teamsource product to manage the source code, etc.  We've had several instances where developers have put an administrative lock on a Teamsource project (thus preventing anyone else from checking in changes for as long as the lock exists) and then have left the company for greener (and hopefully more modern) climes, leaving the admin lock in place.  Our method of handling this is to create a new project, copy in the appropriate files, and move on, but I'm hoping that someone out there can suggest a way to clear the admin lock.  Due to amount of time which has passed (we typically find out that the admin lock was left in place years later when someone has to go in and modify one of the dino-apps) the Windows account which locked it has long since been removed, so the idea of resurrecting the account is likely a non-starter.

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I sympathise. You are probably the only Stack Overflow user that uses Teamsource!!

Comment: Move to SVN. Now.  (Distributed version control is generally more trouble than it's worth, but you do desperately need a better VCS if you're having the issues you describe here.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - you can tell the slow adopters by the arrows in their backs.  :-)

Comment: @WarrenP, Mason Wheeler - excellent suggestions.  Not my decision to make, however (if it was it would have happened years ago), and unlikely to happen.  Put it this way - we have been told that, any day now, we're finally gonna migrate to Windows 7.  Any day now...  :-)

Comment: @Bob They are probably waiting for Windows 8 general avail before moving to Windows 7!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: <shocked look!> What? **Another** version of Windows is being released?!? Well - we'll just have to wait and evaluate *that* before committing to any upgrades! :-)  It's not so much of an issue for me - I mostly do back-end PL/SQL development - but I'm trying to help out a co-worker who's facing this issue.

Comment: @Mason - Disagree. No extra trouble. Centralized version control is more trouble than its worth because it does not separate the tracking and documentation of your coding changes from your inflicting it on other people. It costs more time and money to work with leg-irons around your legs, than it does to work without them. Whether it's the centralized model (and with SVN, the fear of merging preventing temporary branching from ever getting used), or the lock model (VSS and TeamSource), they are blockers for productivity.

Comment: @WarrenP: That's exactly the sort of thing I was talking about. DVCS makes it simple to perform crazy operations that no one needs, like *creating temporary branches and re-merging them later* (why would anyone want to do that?!?) but it turns the actual reason for using source control--keeping your code synchronized with the repository--from a simple one-step process into a 2- or 3-step ordeal.  That's why I say it's more trouble than it's worth.  (Also, why do DVCS people always say that SVN users are afraid of merging, or that merging is scary in SVN? I've never had any trouble with it...)

Comment: Hmm. If you're not scared of it then why did you call "temporary branches" crazy? Hmm?  Those of us who had the disease and are better now, think that your fear of merging is crazy, just like you, oh subversion user, think that users who use locks to avoid merging need to get over their fear of things changing if they don't lock them.

Comment: @warren svn merging works well now

Comment: Good to know. I still think developers in both large and small shops, as well as independent single developers benefit from separating commit from push.

Comment: Hey - perhaps we can have a 2012 Version Control SMACKDOWN!!!  Errrrm...I mean "debate"...  :-}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is pretty old but as nobody answered it and you may still be stuck with the dino, I'm stepping in.
The solution is very simple. Just delete the lock file before opening the project, and TeamSource will happily recreate a fresh lock file with no restrictions.
Look for Locks\lockinfo.dat inside the project's folder.

Comment: Yes, we're still using Delphi and TeamSource. I'll look into that tomorrow. Many thanks!